# How do I get a field value?

Tags: 8, datetime

I am using the [Business Hours](https://www.drupal.org/project/office_hours) module. It allows you to specify two time periods per day, for the 7 days of the week. So you could, for example, say: 9 t 1 Mondays to Fridays, and 2 - 5, Mondays to Fridays.

My problem is getting access to these values as I need to expose it in a custom module. With `print_r($node)`, I can see the following.

```
[field_office_hours] => Array(
  [x-default] => Array(
    [0] => Array(
      [day] => 0
      [starthours] => 900
      [endhours] => 1700
    )
    [1] => Array(
      [day] => 1
      [starthours] => 900
      [endhours] => 1700
    )
    /* Omissis */
  )
)
```

I have no idea how to get this as array. I know that the module requires the "Date" module, so these are probably Date fields, but how do I actually get the values as array?

`$node->field_office_hours->value` doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nevermind, this worked for me:

```
$node->get('field_office_hours')->getValue();
```

Comment: That gives you an array of all the values. It's $node->get('field_office_hours')->$property_name. the property name is often but not always value. You see he properties in your dump, so just use ->day and so on instead of value.